# Get torch parameter name from layer

Tags: python, pytorch

If I have a model with a linear layer `lin = nn.Linear(out_dim, in_dim)` then `lin.named_parameters()` produces a sequence something like `[('weight',Tensor), ('bias',Tensor)]`

But if I run `model.named_parameters()` the sequence is `[('lin.weight',Tensor), ('lin.bias',Tensor)]`.

Is it possible to get the full name of the tensor from the layer? i.e. the name it has inside the root module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules containing other modules will just preprend their own name separated by a period `.` to the ones of the containing modules, so to get the "final" names you just have to split of the last part:

```
import torch
a = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1)
a.b = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1)
a.b.c = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1)
for (fullname, param) in a.named_parameters():
    name = fullname.split('.')[-1]
    print(name, '\t', fullname)
```

Comment: Thanks - that's useful to know. I needed to access the full name but accessing from inside (in your example) c. I ended up using id(c) to get the unique ID of the object instead